# Postal sorting code program using ord() and char() --debugging trouble

Tags: python

I'm stuck with my code for a problem where you get the user to enter a series of numbers/letters and the program returns all viable postal codes using the parameters provided. Here is the question in detail:

> Write a program that reads in numbers from the user. Your program
>   should be capable of tracking/calculating the minimum, maximum, total
>   sum, and average of the numbers entered. When the user enters "q",
>   "Q", or "quit", the program should display the minimum, maximum, total
>   sum, and average of the numbers entered before ending. You can assume
>   that the user will always enter either a number or one of the strings
>   “q”, “Q”, or “quit”. You can also assume the user will always enter at
>   least one number (i.e., they will not immediately choose to quit upon
>   starting the program).
>
> Save your Python program in a file called a2q3.py and add it to your
>   submission zip file. Problem 4 (Postal Sorting Codes)
>
> The forward sortation area code is the first three characters of a
>   Canadian postal code (e.g., the "K1S" in postal code "K1S 5B6") and it
>   has the format:
>
> - First Character: a letter between A and Z
> - Middle Character: a number between 0 and 9 including zero and including 9    -  - Last Character: a letter between A and Z
>
> You will create a program to generate a subset of the possible
>   sortation area codes. Instead of using the entire range, you must
>   write a program using nested loops that generates all the possible
>   codes that fit constraints specified by the user. Your program should
>   request the following information from the user:
>
> 1. The starting letter of the first character
> 2. The ending letter of the first character
> 3. The starting digit of the middle character
> 4. The ending digit of the middle character
> 5. The starting letter of the last character
> 6. The ending letter of the last character
>
> Your program should then print out all possible combinations that fit
>   these constraints. Each of the ranges should include both the starting
>   and ending value, as well as all values in between. You can assume
>   that the user will only enter valid input (i.e., upper case characters
>   for the letters and 0-9 for the digits).   You cannot use Python’s
>   lists, dictionary or set functionality to iterate over the letters.
>   Instead, you should use the ord() function to find the integer values
>   of the specified letters (i.e., the ASCII values) and the chr()
>   function to translate from integers back to letters (for more
>   information on these functions, visit
>   https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). After printing out
>   each of the possible codes, your program should print out the total
>   number of codes before ending.

Here is my code:

```
start_let_first_char=input("Please enter the starting letter of the first character: ")
end_let_first_char=input("Please enter the ending letter of the first character: ")

start_dig_mid=int(input("Please enter the starting digit of the middle character: "))
end_dig_mid=int(input("Please enter the ending digit of the middle character: "))

start_let_last_char=input("Please enter the starting letter of the last character: ")
end_let_last_char=input("Please enter the ending letter of the last character: ")

for x in range(ord(start_let_first_char),ord(end_let_first_char)+1):
    for y in range(start_dig_mid,end_dig_mid +1):
        for z in range(ord(start_let_last_char),ord(end_let_last_char)+1):
            print(chr(x)+str(y)+chr(z))
```

The error I keep getting when I run the code and enter all the letters/digits is:

```
    for z in range(ord(start_let_last_char,ord(end_let_last_char)+1)):  
TypeError: ord() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Thanks, it's fixed and working! I forgot to add a counter for the postal codes. Should I just add a counter and a print(counter) function at the end, or can someone recommend a better way to do that?

Comment: And what is unclear about the error message? You are giving two arguments to `ord`, what were you expecting it to do with them?

Comment: You misplaced a ), I think, it should read: for z in range(ord(start_let_last_char),ord(end_let_last_char)+1):

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry.... I can read that it wants one argument and I'm giving two but I'm just not sure how to fix this/why what I'm trying isn't working. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @sphericalcowboy thank you!!!! that fixed it!

Comment: No problem. You might want to selected my answer then if this fixes the issue.

Comment: @sphericalcowboy I will when the timer lets me :) do you have any suggestions for printing a total of # of codes printed at the end? should i just use a simple counter?

Comment: @kleenexbox: I would just use a simple counter variable here. I updated my answer with the full solution. Note that I changed the variable names, spacing and line length a bit. Personally, I think it is a bit easier to read then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
for z in range(ord(start_let_last_char,ord(end_let_last_char)+1)):
```

Should be:

```
for z in range(ord(start_let_last_char),ord(end_let_last_char)+1):
```

A comma was misplaced there.

With the counter added:

```
letter_1_start = input(
    "Please enter the starting letter of the first character: ")
letter_1_end = input(
    "Please enter the ending letter of the first character: ")

digit_start = int(
    input("Please enter the starting digit of the middle character: "))
digit_end = int(
    input("Please enter the ending digit of the middle character: "))

letter_2_start = input(
    "Please enter the starting letter of the last character: ")
letter_2_end = input(
    "Please enter the ending letter of the last character: ")

counter = 0

for x in range(ord(letter_1_start), ord(letter_1_end) + 1):
    for y in range(digit_start, digit_end + 1):
        for z in range(ord(letter_2_start), ord(letter_2_end) + 1):
            print(chr(x) + str(y) + chr(z))
            counter += 1

print("Total number of codes:", counter)
```